# pass additional variables to internally called call back function

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

i am using a sdk that has a function retrieveMultipleRecords. The function essentially requires an input to be a call back function and in this call back function the data returned from the query is stored. so if i have a callback function DoOperations(mydata) , mydata would automatically retreive the data as an argument from the retrieveMultipleRecords function. I would call it like this

```
retrieveMultipleRecords(DoOperations);  // somehow the data automatically gets passed to the DoOperations function like this i am not even sure how this works)

DoOperations(mydata) 
{

}
```

The problem is that i want to pass additonal arguments information to this DoOperations function. But since its getting data passed to it from the retrieveMultipleRecords internally, when i try to pass aditional arguments to it like this

```
retrieveMultipleRecords(DoOperations(mydata, MyOtherArgumentsIwant));

DoOperations(mydata, AdditionalArgument)
{

}
```

it does not work. How can i pass more arguments into this DoOperation functions and still retrieve the data returned from the retrieveMultipleRecords function? Can someone please give me some examples.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you modify DoOperations so you can send it an array containing mydata + the extra parameters you might send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just do something like:

```
retrieveMultipleRecords(function(mydata) {
    var additionalArgs = "what ever additional args are";
    DoOperation(mydata, additionalArgs);
});  

DoOperations(mydata, additionalArgs) 
{
    //do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `retrieveMultipleRecords` pass arguments that it isn't meant to pass. But you can just include them in the body of `DoOperations` by *defining* it in the same scope as the call to `retrieveMultipleRecords`.